# Could not find any X11 fonts error

Tags: r, path, x11

I am starting to get into R development and I was following a tutorial that in a certain point opens the "X11" to display graphics but when that window opens I get the following error:

> Error in axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :    could
>   not find any X11 fonts Check that the Font Path is correct. In
>   addition: Warning messages: 1: In function (display = "", width,
>   height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :   locale not supported by Xlib: some
>   X ops will operate in C locale 2: In function (display = "", width,
>   height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :   X cannot set locale modifiers

I have been Googling around but I can't find how to fix the "font path" of this application, does anybody know?

**EDIT**

The output of sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.2 (2011-09-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] galgo_1.1         R.oo_1.8.2        R.methodsS3_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.13.2
```

When doing names(X11Fonts()):

```
> names(X11Fonts())
[1] "serif" "sans"  "mono" 
>
```

Comment: According to [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2008-March/004740.html) (which I found by googling your error message) you have an invalid locale. (So says the eminent Professor.)

Comment: yes I found that too and I've tried what it says without luck. Maybe I'm just doing something wrong though. Let me try again.

Answer (score 6):

> I "followed" the admin manual, and set the lines in the .bashrc
>   Setting for the new UTF-8 terminal support in Lion.

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

From http://www.mail-archive.com/r-sig-mac@r-project.org/msg01027.html

Answer (score 2):

What does this return:

```
capabilities("X11")
```

If you are on `.Platform$OS.type == "windows"` then you may need to do some further research. I doubt that X11 is installed there by default. But your edit shows that you are on a mac so try this:

```
names(X11Fonts())
# results on my device 
[1] "serif"        "sans"         "mono"         "Times"       
[5] "Helvetica"    "CyrTimes"     "CyrHelvetica" "Arial"       
[9] "Mincho"
```

When I execute X11() at the R command console in the Mac-GUI I get an X11 window and choosing X11/About X11' I see that I have "XQuartz 2.1.6 (xorg-server 1.4.2-apple33)". I am using Leopard (still), but I thought that recent version of Macs installed X11 support by default and I don't remember needing to point R in the right direction to find it either.

Comment: I'm on OSX (Lion) and it returns True

Comment: So assuming you already executed `X11()`, then I guess we need to see the code.

Comment: the code with which I try to make the graphs? or the one before that?

Comment: The more code the better. And best to add it to your question with an edit.

Comment: Do you have those fonts? I only get 3 fonts and I need to add the rest but I have no idea where to get them from.

Comment: help(X11Fonts) says those were added as of R 2.14.0 and that is what I am using.

Comment: any idea how to install the rest then? I've Googled non-stop the past few days and apparently it's a fairly common error on Linux. On Mac however I haven't found much