# X11 dataentry cannot be loaded in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to View my data in R and get the following:

View(ANES$gwbush)
Error in View(ANES$gwbush) : X11 dataentry cannot be loaded.

I have R and R Studio installed.

I tried resolving it using the advice stated on the following link, but it still doesn't work. I'm new to R, so apologies if I've overlooked anything. Any help would be appreciated.

[Can't use either View() or edit() functions, getting "Error in .External2(C_dataviewer, x, title) : invalid device" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009308/cant-use-either-view-or-edit-functions-getting-error-in-external2c-data)

Comment: Please provide a code snippet which shows which plotting function you were trying to call.  We also need to inspect how you installed any libraries you used in the call.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I'm not quite sure what you mean. The full script that I have run so far is below, but if you need any more information, just let me know.

```html
setwd("Rdata")
library(foreign)
install.packages("foreign")
ANES <- read.csv("ANES2004_reduced.csv")
head(ANES)
names(ANES)
View(ANES$gwbush)
```